# Using dielectric grease on oven broil element connector

Tags: electrical, repair, appliances, oven

Our upper bake element on our oven wasn't working, so I took it apart last night and found that the spade connector had apparently arced and charred and it was totally disconnected.
I had considered cleaning off the charring and re-using the element since there was a decent bit of spade connector left and it measured fine, but for the price of a new element ($20-$40) I am going to replace the bake element just to be safe.
I will also crimp on a new spade connector, but I talked to someone I trust in electrical matters and they mentioned the possible use of dielectric grease to help ensure that the new connection didn't oxidize.
Now the connection itself gets pushed back into insulation outside of the actual baking area, but:
**Is it safe to use dielectric grease on this type of connection?

Do I need to worry about the grease being food safe even if it's not in the oven area?**

[image: Burnt spade connector - male end on element]

[image: Burnt spade connector - female end on wire]

Comment: try graphite powder or iron filings or AL foil; on AC it's not oxidation, it's a poor fit that causes arcing.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to get high tempature spade lugs. Standard tinned copper tend to get loose with heat, the ones I use are rated to 900 f.  As an example I use FR9C-250 terminals from elecdirect (without the name a bunch of gun parts came up).
I have repaired stoves that had some damage but the replacement lug needs full contact with the blade or even high temp connectors will overheat. I am not sure if dielectric grease in this application will do much good but I don't think it would hurt. It may smoke when the element is turned on for the first time or two.

Answer (score 2):

The Dielectric will all burn off in relatively short order. The smoke and smell, you are not going to want in your kitchen.  Make sure you cut back the lead to good clean wire. Oxidation is not a problem in this situation.  You just want a good clean tight connection.  I strip back the insulation twice the length of what I need then fold conductor in half so I have twice the bulk to stick in the barrel of the connector. + what Ed said.

Comment: This isn't a great picture, but the actual tab connection is behind the screw plate (http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/1X0AAOxyUrZSs9fS/$_3.JPG?set_id=2) and buried in the oven insulation (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gUv7ajMRmsw/maxresdefault.jpg). I would think that would protect from a majority of the heat so you shouldn't experience burn off? I should probably test that with the back off. Thanks for the answer!